# Unable to change Identity Specification to Yes in Sql Server table

Tags: sql-server

This may be a dumb question, but why can't I change the Identity Specification or (Is Identity) from 'No' to 'Yes'?

Comment: Yup, it was a dumb question. The primary key column was not highlighted.

Answer (score 38):

Check your column data type.

If it is `varchar` then you can't change identity column.

To change identity column, it should have `int` data type.

Answer (score 20):

You can disable the Option "prevent saving changes that require table re-creation"
but this is strongly unrecommended by msdn.

to do so go to:

Tools -> Options -> Designers
There uncheck: "prevent saving changes that require table re-creation"

Comment: If you notice the comment to my question, I figured out what the problem was.

Comment: lifesaver thanks

Answer (score 16):

You cannot change the IDENTITY property of a column on an existing table. What you can do is add a new column with the IDENTITY property, delete the old column, and rename the new column with the old columns name.

Of course, what happens then (for some people) is that they don't like the fact that the new column appears "at the end" of the list of columns (even though you shouldn't care about the positions of columns - you should always be using their names). In that case, you need to do the same trick, but at a higher level - create a new table (with the column definition altered), copy data from the old table to the new, drop the old table, and rename the new one.

I thought SSMS still tried to pretend that it was possible, by doing the second trick behind the scenes.

Answer (score 14):

Also check to make sure that there isn't a default value or binding on the column.

Comment: This is the real answer of this question in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Remove Default Value or Binding.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment above, you can edit the column order in Visual Studio's design interface.

I've managed to do this successfully. To confirm, the steps are:

1. Add a new column with the IDENTITY property
2. delete the old column,
3. Rename the new column with the old columns name.
4. (Optional) Re-order columns to have the IDENTITY column from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was to change the Data Type to `int` from its default `nchar`. Additionally, I had to refresh my database server connection to get it working.

[image: column properties]

Answer (score 0):

[image: As you can see the yes value for the identity specification is disabled so the other answers above is not applicable for me but following Joy's answer, I saw that I really had a Default Value or Binding. I just omitted the default value and everything i neede was enabled.]

As you can see the yes value for the identity specification is disabled so the other answers above is not applicable for me but following Joy's answer, I saw that I really had a Default Value or Binding. I just omitted the default value and everything i neede was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to find the solution to this, at first I was trying to find a way to change a value from here (it's yes cause I was able to change it using the next way)
[image]

But then by right-clicking -> properties -> Table designer -> Choose Identity column

[image]

Doing this made the "Identity Specifiacation" to "Yes"

Answer (score 0):

I think Firstly you have to check the (isIdentity) checkbox after that you can able to check the Identity Specification Checkbox

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To change it in MSSQL, follow these steps:
Select the column.
Just under Identity Specification there is (Is Identity).
Go to (Is Identity), there will be a drop down, Select 'Yes'.
Identity specification will be changed to 'Yes' too.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?