# SQL Server Management Studio Express crashes when I try to run an ALTER TABLE query to add a PK with auto increment

Tags: sql-server-express, increment, identity-column

I have an existing table where I use existing column (type `INT`) as PK and manually increment its value with each row inserted. I wanted to change it to IDENTITY with auto increment. I found a thread here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862385/sql-server-add-auto-increment-primary-key-to-existing-table) that seems to achieve exactly what I want. But every time I run the ALTER statement, Mgmt Studio crashes.

I had also tried to achieve my above goal by changing the column properties manually (Identity specification/Is Identity:yes) as in this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876785/sql-server-cant-insert-null-into-primary-key-field). But every time I close the table after changing properties, I get an error

> 'Pix' table
>   Unable to modify table.
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'picID', table 'photo.dbo.Tmp_Pix'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot change** an existing column to become an `IDENTITY` column.

What you need to do is:

- create a new column with `INT IDENTITY`
- drop the primary key constraint
- drop the old column
- add the primary key constraint on the new column

The trouble might be - if you already have data in that table - that the new identity values don't necessarily match the old values in your manual `ID` column.

If you need to preserve those, then it gets even more involved:

- create a new table with the proper structure, and make sure that the `ID` column is `INT IDENTITY`
- turn on `IDENTITY_INSERT` for that table
- insert all the rows from the old table into the new one (and in the process, insert the old `ID` values into the new `ID` IDENTITY column)
- turn off `IDENTITY_INSERT` for that table
- drop the old table
- possibly rename the new table