# What is the best practice for a composite PRIMARY KEY?

Tags: sql, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have a table in which I have made two columns as composite PRIMARY KEY. Now I have a confusion.

Let's say I have a table as following:

```
ColA         ColB

X            NULL
X            NULL
```

Both the rows "X    NULL" and "X    NULL" are combined PRIMARY KEY.

So, is this insertion possible? Because the NULL value differs and accordingly both the rows should represent a new combination of data.

Please clarify.

Comment: No. Null values aren't allowed in primary key columns.

Comment: How exactly is `X, NULL` *different* from `X, NULL`?

Comment: First of all no null values are allowed in primary key. And if 2 values are same for 2 columns which will be part of primary key as X , Y and another X,Y , this is also not allowed.because it is not at all different , it is same.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question including all indexes and constraints. Primary key columns can not contain null values, so I guess you only created a unique index, not a primary key constraint

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: [What to do with null values when modeling and normalizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40733625/3404097)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server, can't insert null into primary key field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876785/sql-server-cant-insert-null-into-primary-key-field)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 1):

Primary keys have three properties:

- The key (combination) uniquely identifies each row.
- No component of the keys can be `NULL`.
- A table has only one primary key.

So, by this definition, you cannot declare the two columns to be a primary key.

In general, I am not an advocate of composite primary keys.  I recommend using an auto-incremented primary key for the table (the syntax varies by database).

One nice feature of a numeric identifier is that it captures the insertion order of the values in the table.  Also, many databases cluster the data by the primary key, causing fragmentation on `insert`s and `update`s.